# Complex Amplitudes and their Exp'l Increase/Decrease

Tags: calculus, derivatives, complex-numbers

The following are quotes from a textbook,

> If **S**(t) is represented as a rotating phasor, the angular frequency
>   of the phasor can be thought of as velocity at the end of the phasor.
>   In particular the velocity $\omega$ is always at right angles to the
>   phasor.  $$\mathbf S(t) = Ae^{i\omega t}$$
>   [image]
>
> However when we consider the general case when the velocity vector is
>   inclined at an arbitrary angle $\psi$. In this case is a velocity is
>   given by the symbol $s$ which now is composed of a component
>   $\omega$ at right angle to the phasor as well as a component sigma
>   which is parallel to $s$
>   [image]

**Question1:** I'm not able think about a complex number whose derivative is not $i$ times something, since any complex number can be represented by $e^{it}$, their derivative is given by $i e^{it}$ which means the velocity vector is perpendicular to the current position. But in this "general case" the velocity vector is pointing at an arbitrary angle, how?

**Question 2**: If the velocity vector is pointing in an arbitrary direction, then it's stated that the amplitude increases or decays "**exponentially**" Why is this true? Why not some other rate of decrease or increase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1, you have $S(t)=Ae^{i\omega t}$. You are thinking that $S'(t)=i\omega Ae^{i\omega t}$. That's true **only if** $A$ is a constant in time. If $A$ changes, you have $$S'(t)=i\omega Ae^{i\omega t}+\frac{dA}{dt}e^{i\omega t}$$

If the angle $\psi$ is constant, then we have the ratio between the two components (radial and tangential) is constant. $$\frac{\frac{dA}{dt}}{\omega A}=c$$ or $$\frac{dA}{dt}=c\omega A$$
The solution of this equation is an exponential $A(t)=A_0e^{c\omega t}$.

Comment: Thanks you , but I don't understand what you mean by the angle between the two components, and how you arrived at that eqn

Comment: Sorry, I did not say it right. I should have said "if $\psi$ is constant".The tangent of $\psi$ is the ratio between $\sigma$ and $\omega$ in the second figure. Instead of $\omega$ it should be $A\omega$, and $\sigma=\frac{dA}{dt}$.